# PDF File not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I have a Input Field which have same name. **pdf[]**
I am inserting and uploading it into database it is perfectly inserting into database. but not uploading into **uploads folder**  there is a problem with `do_upload();`

```
  $items=$_FILES['pdf']['name']; 
  $count = count($items);
  $lstid=$this->FetchData->getLastInserted();
  for($i=0; $i<=$count-1; $i++){
      //echo $img[$i];
      $img = $_FILES['pdf']['name'][$i];
      $timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
      $datetime = new DateTime("now", $timezone);
      $date = $datetime->format("D_M_d_Y_H_i_s");
      $ext = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $new_name=$i.'_'.$state_id.'_'.$date;
      if(!empty($img)){
         $imagenamefordatabase = $new_name.'.'.$ext;
      }
      else{
         $imagenamefordatabase ='';
      }
      $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
      // set the filter image types
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
      $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
      //load the upload library
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');
      $data['upload_data'] = '';
      //if not successful, set the error message
      if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pdf[]')) {
         $data = array('Success' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      } 
      else { 
         //else, set the success message
         $data = array('Success' => "Upload success!");
         $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
      }
      $sampleresult = array(
        'Report_Print_Data_Id' => $lstid,

        'Sample_Report' => $imagenamefordatabase
      );

      $this->AddData->addReportResult($sampleresult);
  }
```

Comment: Please share `$this->upload->do_upload` method definition as well.

Comment: @jeroen this was my correct code. i have to upload multiple file with name of the inputs are same. __pdf[]__ i am getting extensions because of saving file with different name. after the i am using the upload library of code Igniter. then saving name into MySQL database.

Comment: @NareshKumarNakka $this->upload->do_upload() is the codeigniter default library.

Comment: you need to use like this
    $this->upload->do_upload('pdf');

Comment: yes i used but not uploading. when i have single input name. __pdf__ then it is working when i change it to __pdf[]__ then not uploading. error comming __You did not select a file to upload.__

Answer (score 0):

Change The filed name As userfile.

config file size in controller and try.

if any error please show.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I solved the answer by.  Declaring the variable above for loop. __files=$_FILE;__ and within for loop __ $_FILES['pdf']['name']=$files['pdf']['name'][$i];__ and do_upload('pdf');

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass field name only without large brackets `[]`. Update the following part of your code.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pdf')) {
     $data = array('Success' => $this->upload->display_errors());
} 
else 
{ 
     //else, set the success message
     $data = array('Success' => "Upload success!");
     $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
}
```